# Spaceship outruns the end of the universe - influences evolution on another planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

There is a book I read in the 1980s or 1990s from a Ca.  library. It was a hard copy not a paperback. It is not "To Outlive Eternity/Tau Zero" by Poul Anderson (I have that one). It may have been written by a woman or someone whose last name starts with an "L".

A large crew of men and women are in a new super fast space ship. They are being chased by someone and they outrun the collapse of the universe, but they have lost their home planet. They watch as the universe is reborn. They go into orbit around a planet that looks like it can support life like theirs. They are moving super fast. They look like a ring of radiation going around the planet. They put down 10 super metal markers with scientific info onto the surface of the planet.
They watch the planet develop and form life like the dinosaurs and then evolve into human like life forms.

There are 2 warring countries on the planet. They block or turn off the sun to freeze the planet and force the countries to form one world government. The planet gets freezing cold and the people start to freeze. The countries agree to form one world government. The people on the ship are welcomed to the planet.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but it is not the Gentle Giants of Ganymede. Thanks  Richard