# Trying to identify a science fiction space opera written by a woman that I read between 1976 and 1985

Tags: story-identification

There is a book I read between 1976 and 1985 from the Milpitas, Ca. library.

It was a hard copy not a paperback.

It is not, [*To Outlive Eternity/Tau Zero* by Poul Anderson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1407239139), I have that one.

It may have been written by a woman or someone  whose last name starts with an “L.”

A large crew of men and women are in a new super fast space ship
They are being chased by someone but they outrun them. They outrun the collapse of the universe in a super fast spaceship, but they have lost their home planet.

They watch as the universe collapses and is reborn.

They come across a planet made of super metal and they rebuild their ship with it

They go into orbit around a planet that looks like it can support life like theirs.  They are moving super fast. They look like a ring of radiation going around the planet.

They put down 10 super metal markers with scientific info onto the surface of the planet

They watch the planet develop and form life like the dinosaurs and then evolve

Into human like life forms.

They broadcast  movies of the early life forms and their visits to early civilizations down to the planet.

They identify the positions of all 10 markers on the planet, some had been lost, then they were found.

There are  2 warring countries on the planet.

They block or turn off the sun to freeze the planet and force the countries to form one world government.

The planet gets freezing cold and the people start to freeze.

The countries agree to form one world government.

The people on the ship are welcomed to the planet.

Comment: Sounds [familiar](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72059/spaceship-outruns-the-end-of-the-universe-influences-evolution-on-another-plan)

Comment: Please don't repost the same question twice. If you want to bump the old one back to the front page so it gets more attention, you can always **edit** it.

Comment: Sorry about posting it twice over the years. I would rather delete the old post. I don't know how to delete the old post. I can delete all the words but I am not sure if that will work. Richard

Comment: @Richardb3530 If you prefer the text in this question over the old one, why not just edit the old one with the text in this one?